# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. help pz

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to add "contact us" page on my website. But when send mail button is clicked above error occures.

code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(txtMail.Text);
        msg.To.Add("ganesh.bodke07@gmail.com");
        msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        sc.Port = 25;
        sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtMail.Text, Password.Text);

        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Send(msg);
        Response.Write("Thanx for contacting us");
    }
    catch(Exception exy)
    {
        Response.Write(exy.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing port to `587`

Comment: Also while using gmail smtp server, make sure you have turned on access for Less secure apps from google account settings.

Comment: Below is the Gmail SMTP settings.
Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address (e.g. example@gmail.com)

Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
With Gmail 2-step authentication enabled, use an application-specific Gmail password.
Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes